# Sharepoint alternative for linux

Tags: server, linux

Is there a Sharepoint alternative / imitation for Linux Server ?

I am looking for a linux webdav server (or PHP webdav server) that could imitate the "official" SharePoint webdav server in order to connect it to MS Office Apps on iOS devices... I have already tried to use sabreDav server (written in PHP) but Word for iOS denied the connection...